# Inbox notification updates broke the chat inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, global-inbox

The recent changes to the inbox notifications have also broken the inbox in the chat top bar:

[image: Screenshot of an inbox open on chat.SE, that has jumped up above the topbar, no site icons, with a second, ghost inbox behind it, and no way to close it]

The inbox has jumped to be overlaying the topbar, instead of it being in its proper place. There is a second, phantom inbox visible it. There are no site favicons (although I believe that's been broken for a while), and, most annoyingly, there's no way to close it. Clicking to the side closes the phantom inbox, but <kbd>esc</kbd> doesn't work and I can't access the inbox button to click it again.

I use a userscript that shows me the topbar even in chat rooms, so this is especially annoying because it means that I can't check my inbox from chat anymore without breaking things. (I already couldn't view Teams content from the chat inbox, but that was a minor issue.)

Comment: Seeing it now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just pushed the fix for the issue. During the implementation of the new inbox features we had to touch existing code, too, and unfortunately we caused this bug.

Thank you very much for the report and even more for your patience. We're sorry you've experienced those issues and hope that the planned improvements will make up for it!